# scapy send(packet) is not working on one NIC windows

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7-x64, scapy

I have windows 7 64-bit with python 2.7 running on it. I also have latest version of scapy 2.3.3 for windows. I am trying to send some packets via scapy and capture on wireshark. I have two NICs one of which has static IP and other dynamic. Over the NIC having dynamic IP I am able to generate traffic via scapy and capture it, but cannot capture packets over the NIC with static IP. Although scapy says that the packet is sent. but unable to capture it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By selecting the correct interface I was able to solve the problem. To check the available interfaces open cmd and type 'ipconfig /all'. Which will show all available interfaces. While generating traffic via scapy give the name of interface through which traffic is supposed to go. e.g.

```
send(IP(dst="xx.xx.xx.xx", src="xx.xx.xx.xx")/TCP(), iface="eth0")
```

Windows has different names of interfaces. The name of the interface is mentioned in front of description when 'ipconfig /all' is used.